# Hovering in a table to affect a header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure if this is even possible to accomplish without JavaScript, but it would be preferable.

This is kind of what my page looks like:

```
 ____________________________
| TITLE                      |     |This is a fixed header. I want "TITLE"
|----------------------------|     |to be the name of the row, and I want it
|   _______    _______    ___|     |to show when I hover over one of the 
|  |       |  |       |  |   |     |image rows.
|  |       |  |       |  |   |     |
|  |_______|  |_______|  |___|     | [The boxes are the images.]
|   _______    _______    ___|     |
|__|_______|__|_______|__|___|     |
```

```css
header {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: fixed !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  padding-top: 100px;
  /*equal to the height of your header */
}

r1n {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline;
}

r1n:hover {
  display: none
}

table tr:hover ~ header r1n {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<header>

  <r1n>TITLE_NAME</r1n>
</header>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Is there a CSS method/trick to make the fixed header show the row's name?
Maybe by concealing a bunch of divs in the header and displaying them depending on which row the cursor is on?

**EDIT:**

**@AndrewBone: CSS and JS solution**

**@Dekel: JS solution**

**EDIT^2: Just... just look at all the answers. They're all good. CSS/JS/JQ.**

Comment: Since you're using a fiddle link... could you also include all relevant code in the question itself?

Comment: Not possible with CSS. CSS can't select UP the DOM. Javascript will be required.

Comment: In a different question I asked (yesterday), I got a solution for using a checkbox in the header and a hover on a cell. I assumed it could be similarly applied. Is this not true?

Comment: Also, you seem to be creating non-standard elements `<r1n>` You really shouldn't do that unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: ...non-standard elements? welp, that's another term for my vocab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125510/discussion-between-alexg-and-paulie-d).

Comment: Ahhh. I see. Thank you! Is there a simple JS function I should look into that'll help me?

Comment: If you're showing a bunch of images, rather than data, using `table` may not be the best choice, semantically speaking. Might be better to use unordered lists.

Comment: @Paulie_D It's possible with a little outside the box thinking :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see lots of people saying this isn't possible, it is though I would never suggest you use it in practice.

Here is an example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
table {
  margin: 18px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #DDD;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #FFF;
}
tr:hover {
  background: tomato;
}
tr[data-header]:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-header);
  position: absolute;
  top: -19px;
  left: -1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr data-header="Header 1">
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-header="Header 2">
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-header="Header 3">
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-header="Header 4">
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've added a header attribute to each tr also I've added a pseudo element, this pseudo element puts some `content`, which in this example is taken from the header attribute thanks to `attr(header)`, and positions it where we want it in relation to the parent, `table`, just like that we have some code that works and is JS free. But honestly, use JS if you can :-)

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Here's a pure javascript solution

```js
const trSel = document.querySelectorAll("tr[data-header]");
for (let i = 0; i < trSel.length; i++) {
  trSel[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt) {
    let headSel = trSel[i].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(":scope > .header");
    headSel.innerHTML = trSel[i].dataset.header;
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #DDD;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #FFF;
}
tr[data-header]:hover {
  background: tomato;
}
td {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="header">
    Placeholder!
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr data-header="Table 1 Row 1">
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-header="Table 1 Row 2">
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-header="Table 1 Row 3">
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-header="Table 1 Row 4">
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<h2>
Wild second table appeared
</h2>

<div>
  <div class="header">
    Placeholder!
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr data-header="Table 2 Row 1">
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-header="Table 2 Row 2">
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-header="Table 2 Row 3">
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-header="Table 2 Row 4">
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

It uses the same principles, but now it's actually updating the text so when you move your mouse away it can keep the last selected row. It works with multiple tables too.

**EDIT 2:** slight edit, I've changed to using data-header instead of header, just because that's what you're meant to do ;-)

Comment: Ooh, that's pretty cool! I've started looking for JS alternatives, but nothing has popped out yet. How would you suggest I do it with JS?

Comment: Also, with your non-recommended solution, would it be possible to "set" the header name unless I scroll over another table, in which case it's replaced?

Comment: With this solution the "title" would only be visible while a row is hovered, so way to set anything or have it stay there without a hover.

Comment: @AndrewBone, very nice CSS solution! You got +1 from me on that :)

Comment: @AlexG I've updated my answer to have a pure JS solution too.

Comment: @AlexG @AndrewBone i gave you a +1 for the css solution. very nice . the problem is that the heading isn't fixed.you  might use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute` on `:after` pseudo element, but that would work only in this specific situation when the table is the first element ( after the heading ) inside the page.

Comment: @MihaiT should work with things above and below it, because the parent (table) is position relative #CSSHacks, here have a look https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/k19yo1oh/

Comment: @AndrewBone can it still work if I have a <header><div class="header">[other-stuff]</div></header>? It doesn't react for me -- I'm assuming because of the "querySelector(":scope > .header")" part.

Comment: Nevermind! Changing it from querySelector(":scope > .header") to querySelector(":scope > header .header") fixed it. [Is there a reason why this script *must* be after all of my other html code?]

Comment: @AlexG you need it to run once the page is made, or it can't see what's there (JS looks at the page, the DOM, rather than the code)

Comment: @AndrewBone well it works with position absolute ( it will always stay on top of the table with pos relative ) but, as i understood from the question, the header ( where the title appears ) should be fixed . so when you scroll down the table ( which will be much higher than in the example because it will contain images ) , when hovering over row3 for eg, you should see the title ( even though you don't see the top of the table ) . that's why i said that the css solution won't work if you want to have a fixed header

Answer (score 1):

Just because you asked for a js solution in the comment @AndrewBone's answer.

Notice the usage of `index` to find the current position of the hovered `tr` inside the table. Index starts in 0, hence the `+1` you see there.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#tbl1 tr').hover(function() {
    i = $('#tbl1 tr').index(this) + 1;
    $('r1n').text('Row ' + i);
  });
});
```

```css
header {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: fixed !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  padding-top: 100px;
  /*equal to the height of your header */
}

r1n {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline;
}
#tbl1 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#tbl1 td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <r1n>TITLE_NAME</r1n>
</header>

<table id="tbl1" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it harder to do this without using a library? Alternatively, can a library be included by doing <script>[all-the-text-in-the-link]</script>?

Comment: Your question has 2 parts (that are not related). 1. Yes - you can put the code inside the script tags - you don't have to use the `src="http....jquery.min.js"`, however I will not recommend that (caching/file size and everything). 2. It's not hard to implement without the library, but it will take you much more code :)

Answer (score 1):

i see that you have some answers ( and an accepted one ) just wanted to put a JQ solution with targets here if anyone prefers something like this :) ( i guess i doesn't hurt another answer )

in this code, `table` and `header` are siblings , even if in your posted code, body is the parent of table and sibling with header. here, everything is automatically inserted inside the default `<body>` tag

```js
$("table tr").hover(function(){
   var data = $(this).attr('data-target'),
       target = $(this).parents('table').siblings('header').find('h1')
       $(target).each(function(){
             if($(this).attr('id') == data) {
             $(this).toggle()
             }
  
       })
})
```

```css
header {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: fixed !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  padding-top: 100px;
  /*equal to the height of your header */
}

header h1 {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  margin:0;
}


table tr {
  cursor:pointer;
  background:blue;

}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background:red;
}
table,td { 
  border-collapse:collapse;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>

  <h1 id="row1">Title row1 </h1>
  <h1 id="row2">Title row2 </h1>
  <h1 id="row3">Title row3 </h1>
  <h1 id="row4">Title row4 </h1>
</header>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr data-target="row1">
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
     <tr data-target="row2">
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-target="row3">
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-target="row4">
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```